# Turning a JavaScript function into jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to turn the JavaScript in [this](http://eilenna.tumblr.com/jsmenu) example into jQuery.

Basically I've jerry-rigged two scripts together. One is jQuery; creates the "active" function. But the hide/display layer function is in Javascript, and there's too much code for my liking, I'm thinking it must be possible to cut it down into something simple and effective with jQuery.

FYI, I just started out with Javascript and jQuery.

Help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>JSMenu</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function HideLayer(d) { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none"; }
function DisplayLayer(d) { document.getElementById(d).style.display = "block"; };

 $(function() {
    $('div.menuitem').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $this.addClass('active');
    })
});
</script>

<style>
#menuholder {width:100px; float:left; border-bottom:solid thin #000;}
.menuitem {border-top:solid thin #000; border-left:solid thin #000; border-right:solid thin #000;}
.menuitem:hover {cursor:pointer; color:#555}
.active {font-weight:bold; color:#000}
.active:hover {color:#000}
#layerholder {float:left; margin-left:20px; width:50px; height:50px; border:solid thin;}
.layer {padding-left:3px; font-size:36px; display:none;}
</style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="menuholder">
<div onClick="DisplayLayer('firstLayer');HideLayer('secondLayer');HideLayer('thirdLayer');HideLayer('fourthLayer')" class="menuitem">Item 1</div>
<div onClick="HideLayer('firstLayer');HideLayer('thirdLayer');HideLayer('fourthLayer');DisplayLayer('secondLayer')" class="menuitem">Item 2</div>
<div onClick="HideLayer('firstLayer');HideLayer('secondLayer');HideLayer('fourthLayer');DisplayLayer('thirdLayer')" class="menuitem">Item 3</div>
<div onClick="HideLayer('firstLayer');HideLayer('secondLayer');HideLayer('thirdLayer');DisplayLayer('fourthLayer')" class="menuitem">Item 4</div>
</div>

<div id="layerholder">  
<div class="layer" id="firstLayer">1</div>
<div class="layer" id="secondLayer">2</div>
<div class="layer" id="thirdLayer">3</div>
<div class="layer" id="fourthLayer">4</div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery is a JavaScript framework, not a separate language.

Comment: Yes, I know. That's the thing; I want to "framework" the Javascript function =) Morph it together with the jQuery function. Preferably remove script from the html. Right now there's an awful lot of code after "onClick".

Comment: jQuery is a separate API. Clearly OP wants to convert the native DOM API calls to jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change your HTML to:

```
<div id="menuholder">
   <div rel="firstLayer" class="menuitem">Item 1</div>
   <div rel="secondLayer" class="menuitem">Item 2</div>
   ...
</div>
```

And then use this jQuery:

```
$('.menuitem').click(function() {
    $('.layer').hide();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#' + $(this).attr('rel')).show();
});
```

This also not 100% perfect as `rel` is not a valid attribute for `div` elements. You should consider changing the `div`s to `a` elements (and use the `href` attribute) which has the benefit that the browser also jumps to the linked element.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WDRZq/)

**Update:** If you decide to go with links, it would be:

```
<div id="menuholder">
   <a href="#firstLayer" class="menuitem">Item 1</div>
   <a href="#secondLayer" class="menuitem">Item 2</div>
   ...
</div>
```

and

```
$('.menuitem').click(function() {
    $('.layer').hide();
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this.href).show();
});
```

Comment: Oh, I just realized that there were two containers.

Comment: @felix-kling How should the jquery look like if I change the DIVs to As?

Comment: @felix-kling Something's wrong; it doesn't show the layers? [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5KAb)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is JavaScript. There is absolutely no reason to "convert" anything.

And jQuery has hide and show functions built in.

```
$('#id').hide();
```

And as for your onClick event..

1. It should be lowercase.
2. You could just do `$('.layer').hide();$('#specificLayer').show();`.

Answer (score 0):

The script on that page already uses jquery as shown by the `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">` at the top, and the use of the $ sign before variables after it. Jquery is just a set of javascript functions in a library, so you can combine them without issue.

Comment: `$` could be anything, it does not mean that jQuery is used. Only including the script is a strong indicator that jQuery is used **but** it could still be overwritten by another framework, such as Prototype.

Comment: Just including jquery does not mean its used. Using the $ afterward without jquery.noconflict does.